# chrome ctrl+f in delveloper tools 'Elements' doesn't work well

Tags: google-chrome, search, ctrl

When I use chrome developer tools, the 'Elements'(DOM) one can only search DOM elements like 'div''p''style' and so on, but cannot search the kind like 'abc' in 'class="abcde"'.
Once I reinstall Chrome, it may work. However after a while, it dosen't work again.
Should I set anything about its config? How should I do?

---add more detail about my working environment--
os: Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit SP1 ( DirectX 11 )
chrome version : 38.0.2125.104 m
--about my question--
The DOM search tools can search any word in DOM normally, even it is not exactly a word.For example, if a DOM element is :

```html
<div class="classA" id="idA">abc</div>
```

Using ctrl+F in DOM ,tying in 'classA','idA','abc' it would match some result,even typing in'A' can match 2 results. But in my situtation, only typing in 'div' has result.

This morning I found the DOM search function works again, but I still be confused with it. It may not work next time..

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question

Comment: Can you provide more information like what environment you working on?

Comment: I add some details following.

Answer (score 0):

i experience the same thing on osx chrome, searching for '.classname' or '#classid" will match (only matches on a full match) but 'classname' does not. this is a recent change, hopefully just a bug in chrome.

it's like it is running jQuery('< yourtexthere >') and showing the results.

Answer (score 0):

It's a recent bug for Chrome under Linux. I think it's from ver. 38.